# bash + run cli in order to run command from user hdfs

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, hdfs

I have the following lines in my bash script , in order to fix the replicated files in HDFS

reference - https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Fix-Under-replicated-blocks-in-HDFS-manually/ta-p/244746

```
  su hdfs -c "hdfs fsck / | grep 'Under replicated' | awk -F':' '{print \$1}' > /tmp/under_replicated_files"

  su hdfs -c "for hdfsfile in `cat /tmp/under_replicated_files`; do echo "Fixing $hdfsfile :" ;  hadoop fs -setrep 3 $hdfsfile; done"
```

when script is running its failed on

```
: ;  hadoop fs -setrep 3 ; done: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `/user/ambari-qa/.staging/job_1571913174208_0001/job.split'
: ;  hadoop fs -setrep 3 ; done: -c: line 1: `/user/ambari-qa/.staging/job_1571913174208_0001/job.split'
```

while the file- `/tmp/under_replicated_files` , contain:

```
/user/ambari-qa/.staging/job_1571913174208_0001/job.jar
/user/ambari-qa/.staging/job_1571913174208_0001/job.split
/user/ambari-qa/.staging/job_1571913174208_0003/job.jar
```

where I am wrong with the following line?

```
  su hdfs -c "for hdfsfile in `cat /tmp/under_replicated_files`; do echo "Fixing $hdfsfile :" ;  hadoop fs -setrep 3 $hdfsfile; done"
```

note:

when I do the same steps manual from user - `hdfs` , then we not have any problem

example:

```
su hdfs

$ hdfs fsck / | grep 'Under replicated' | awk -F':' '{print $1}' > /tmp/under_replicated_files
$ for hdfsfile in `cat /tmp/under_replicated_files`; do echo "Fixing $hdfsfile :" ;  hadoop fs -setrep 3 $hdfsfile; done
```

we tried also with

```
su hdfs -c "for hdfsfile in `cat /tmp/under_replicated_files`; do echo \"Fixing $hdfsfile :\" ;  hadoop fs -setrep 3 $hdfsfile; done"
```

but we get:

```
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `/user/ambari-qa/.staging/job_1571913174208_0001/job.split'
bash: -c: line 1: `/user/ambari-qa/.staging/job_1571913174208_0001/job.split'
```

Comment: now I get : bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `/user/ambari-qa/.staging/job_1571913174208_0001/job.split'
bash: -c: line 1: `/user/ambari-qa/.staging/job_1571913174208_0001/job.split'

Comment: What if you remove the echo command completely?

Comment: I rty this - su hdfs -c "for hdfsfile in `cat /tmp/under_replicated_files`; do  ;  hadoop fs -setrep 3 $hdfsfile; done"    , but the same error

Comment: How about the xargs options listed in your linked post? The error you're getting is related to the $hdfsfile variable, so you'll have to remove/fix it